# Can Task MaxDegreeOfParallelism can report after finish handle file?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I am opening n concurrent threads in my function:

```
List<string> _files = new List<string>();

    public void Start()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = _tokenSource.Token;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Parallel.ForEach(_files,
                    new ParallelOptions
                    {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 //limit number of parallel threads 
                    },
                    file =>
                    {
                        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                            return;
                        //do work...
                    });
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }

        }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
            t =>
            {
                //finish...
            }
        , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
        );
            }
```

there is a way to know while this function still processing that 1 file finish ? i am now talking about `ContinueWith` which this is the case after all my `list` has finished.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I perfectly understand your issue but you could use some standard notification through a method:

```
public void Start()
{
    CancellationTokenSource _tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = _tokenSource.Token;

    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(_files,
                new ParallelOptions
                {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 //limit number of parallel threads 
                },
                file =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;
                    //do work...
                    OnDone(file);
                });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        { }

    }, _tokenSource.Token).ContinueWith(
        t =>
        {
            //finish...
        }
    , TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() //to ContinueWith (update UI) from UI thread
    );
}

public void OnDone(string fileName)
{
    // Update the UI, assuming you're using WPF
    someUIComponent.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(...)
}
```

You may need additional locks if you update some shared state, but to only update the UI (e.g. a row in a datagrid or an element in a list) should be fine because the synchronization is enforced by the dispatcher invocation.